# Concatenate integers as string

Tags: arduino-uno

How can i concatenate integers as a single string?

```
int out1, out2, out3 = 0;

    out1 = digitalRead(r1);
    out2 = digitalRead(r2);
    out3 = digitalRead(r3);
```

I tried like so, between others, with no luck.

```
Serial.write(out1 + "" + out2 + "" + out3);
```

For example the expected result when all outputs are `HIGH` should be `111`, while when only the `r3` output is `HIGH` it should be `001`

All i want, is reporting to the sender of the serial command, the pins state

Comment: Since you only use `1`s and `0`s, you could also convert it to a three digit number, and print that `Serial.write(out1*100 + out2*10 + out3);`

Comment: @Gerben: You mean `Serial.println()`.

Comment: Correction: `Serial.println(out1*100 + out2*10 + out3);` (thanks @EdgarBonet)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're just outputting to serial you don't need to concatenate - just print each bit separately, such as:

```
Serial.print(out1);
Serial.print(",");
Serial.print(out2);
Serial.print(",");
Serial.println(out3);
```

You should avoid using String as it's not good on devices with small amounts of memory like Arduinos. Instead if you really need to concatenate numbers you should use a C string and maybe `snprintf` to format the numbers into it:

```
char out[30];
snprintf(out, 30, "%d,%d,%d", out1, out2, out3);
```

Answer (score 1):

I second Majenko's points about just printing the bits separately if
possible, and avoiding `String` objects.

However, if you do need to build such a string (not String object, just
plain C string), you don't need `sprintf()`, which is quite a big
function: you can build the string character by character. For example:

```c++
char out[4];  // 3 + 1 char for the termination character
out[0] = out1==HIGH ? '1' : '0';
out[1] = out2==HIGH ? '1' : '0';
out[2] = out3==HIGH ? '1' : '0';
out[3] = '\0';  // add NUL termination
Serial.println(out);
```

This is using the [ternary operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:#C), which here means “if `out1` is
`HIGH`, then use the character `'1'`, otherwise use `'0'`”.

Now, it just happens that in Arduino `HIGH` means 1 and `LOW` means 0.
And single digit numbers can be converted into character by just adding
the numeric code of character “0”, which is 48 but can written as `'0'`
in C++. Thus you can write:

```c++
out[0] = out1 + '0';  // convert number to character
```

And you can put all together as:

```c++
char out[4];  // 3 + 1 char for the termination character
out[0] = digitalRead(r1) + '0';
out[1] = digitalRead(r2) + '0';
out[2] = digitalRead(r3) + '0';
out[3] = '\0';  // add NUL termination
Serial.println(out);
```

Answer (score 1):

Serial.write(b) prints one byte not a string. Use print() to print strings and numbers.

```
Serial.print(digitalRead(r1));
Serial.print(digitalRead(r2));
Serial.println(digitalRead(r3));
```